# Mutual information: Proving $I(X;Y)=\underset{r(x),s(y)}{\min}D_{KL}[p(x,y)\mid\mid r(x)\cdot s(y)]$

Tags: probability-theory, derivatives, information-theory

I was asked to show that for two discrete RVs $X,Y$ with joint distribution $p\left(x,y\right)$ and marginal distributions $p\left(x\right)$ and $p\left(y\right)$, it holds that for any two distributions $r\left(x\right)$ and $s\left(y\right)$

$$I\left(X;Y\right)=\underset{r\left(x\right),s\left(y\right)}{\min}D_{KL}\left[p\left(x,y\right)\mid\mid r\left(x\right)\cdot s\left(y\right)\right]$$

Now,

$$I\left(X;Y\right)=D_{KL}\left[p\left(x,y\right)\mid\mid p\left(x\right)\cdot p\left(y\right)\right]=\sum_{x,y}p\left(x,y\right)\log\frac{p\left(x,y\right)}{p\left(x\right)p\left(y\right)}$$

so this amounts to showing $$\underset{r\left(x\right),s\left(y\right)}{\min}\sum_{x,y}p\left(x,y\right)\log\frac{p\left(x,y\right)}{r\left(x\right)s\left(y\right)}=\sum_{x,y}p\left(x,y\right)\log\frac{p\left(x,y\right)}{p\left(x\right)p\left(y\right)}$$

but how does one show this? Do I need to differentiate w.r.t. $r\left(x\right)$ and $s\left(y\right)$? Is that possible?

Comment: This amounts to showing that for every pair of distributions $r,s$ it holds that $$ \sum_{x,y} p_{xy} \log \frac{p_{x}p_{y}}{r_x s_y} \ge 0.$$ Breaking the log immediately yields that the LHS is $D(p_X\|r) + D(p_Y\|s)$ and the inequality is then obvious, as is the equality condition.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I don't follow, how does this inequality yield the requested result?

Comment: $$D(p_{XY}\|r_X s_Y) - D(p_{XY}\|p_Xp_Y) = \sum p_{xy} \log \frac{p_{xy}}{r_x s_y} - \sum p_{xy} \log \frac{p_{xy}}{p_x p_y}$$ equals the expression in the comment. So, the inequality shows that $D(p_{XY}\|r_X s_Y) \ge I(X;Y)$  for every $(r,s).$ I suppose you do have to show that $I$ is the minimum, but this is trivial - just set $r,s$ to be the appropriate marginals.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I see, thanks! Do you want to post this as an answer? I'd be happy to accept.